# Audio Recording and playback VC++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, audio

Hi folks I am planning on recording audio, and later play it back, for on of my projects. The requirement is that it should be c++ ( Visual studio 2008 ) compatible. Rest of our application is mostly in silverlight/ VC++. I have worked with NAudio before in C#, but nothing on vc++.

---

I would like to know what is best suited for my needs :

1. VC++ (Visual studio 2008) 32 bit compatible.
2. Only need to record/playback. No fancy functionalities needed.
3. Only 32 bit windows 7/vista targeted. Multi-platform functionality is unnecessary.
4. Need a quickfix code. Doesn't matter if things are slow, requires extra computation power, etc. As long as it doesn't crash,  and does what it should properly, I am good.
5. is free ( at least for research).

---

Can you suggest something that would be best  for me ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: waveIt/waveOut are too complex for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is using MCI. Basically, you can use [`mciSendCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757160(VS.85).aspx) (or [`mciSendString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757161(VS.85).aspx)) to send an [`MCI_RECORD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743456(VS.85).aspx) command to do recording, or an [`MCI_PLAY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743451(VS.85).aspx) to do playback.